# Make iPhone app paid version replace free version on install from app store

Tags: iphone, app-store

I just released a free version of a paid app store application, and I would like the paid version to replace the free version on install.

During testing I had this working by giving them both the same app id and signing them with the same certificate.

When I submitted the new free version to Apple it would not let me use the existing app id, and I created a new one for the free version.

The side effect of this is now my paid version no longer replaces the free version on install. The user ends up with both installed on their phone.

How can I make the paid version replace the free one?

---

**EDIT 1:** I want both the free and paid version of the app in the app store at the same time. The free version has a link in it to buy the paid version.

**EDIT 2:** I was thinking I had seen other apps from the store do this, but maybe I was mistaken.

Comment: Were you able to find out the solution. I am also looking something very similar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as the device is concerned, it has two different apps with two different certificates.  The user will have to manually delete the old one.  If they both have the same name and icon, it will be somewhat confusing for them.  In my opinion, your free version should have "free" or "lite" somewhere in the name to make this easier.

Comment: Yes, I did add lite to the name and icon of the app.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to do this. The closest you can come is to have a free app with an in-app purchase to upgrade to the full features—that would all happen within one app so in a sense it fits your 'replace' criteria but not your 'both in the store' criteria. This functionality probably wasn't available when you originally posted your question—you couldn't have in-app purchasing in free apps originally—but it is now.

There still is not, however, a way to do what you were specifically requesting.

Answer (score 2):

This is two different apps - and you can't get around the app store by doing this.

Perhaps you want to check out the new StoreKit API in iPhone OS 3.0 - this might make things a bit simpler for you.

With StoreKit you can have a single installable app - that can have extra functions unlocked once the user pays for them.

Edit: Found out that the initial app can't be installed for free - you have to pay a small amount for it.