# Does full version of application replace the lite version or it is downloaded as new app?

Tags: iphone, upgrade

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Make iPhone app paid version replace free version on install from app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982876/make-iphone-app-paid-version-replace-free-version-on-install-from-app-store)

Hi all iPhone developers,

can anybody knows that, 
when i am uploading my new version of application to app store for upgrading it.
if there is change in my databse so it needs to delete older version to take effect.
Now, when user upgrade it , then apple will remove first app and download newone or it just upgrade the application?

Comment: your question could use some rewording. right now it's not that clear and the grammar is terrible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this question may be what you are looking for:

[Make iPhone app paid version replace free version on install from app store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982876/make-iphone-app-paid-version-replace-free-version-on-install-from-app-store)